# "jockeying begins to take on Gov. Ron DeSantis and U.S. Sen. Marco Rubio in 2022,"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Currently reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/sunshine-state-dims-dems-amid-151941754.html) there is a line,

> **As the jockeying begins to take on Gov. Ron DeSantis and U.S. Sen. Marco Rubio in 2022**, Democrats' disadvantage against Republicans is deeper than ever, as they try to develop a cohesive strategy and rebuild a statewide party deep in debt and disarray.

Does that bold part mean the (democrats') election effort(race) has already begun to oust Gov. Ron DeSantis and the senator Marco Rubio in 2022?

Since the definition of the word "jockey" from dictionaries is a bit vague, kindly teach me.

Thank you in advance(m_m).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full phrase is "jockeying for position". The image is that of jockeys in a horse race.

Various Democrats are fighting to be first in the race for their party's nomination for Senate and governorship.

Answer (score 2):

The expression is "to [jockey for position](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/jockey-for-position)".  It means to use any method to get in a better position to win a race. (Horse riders are called jockeys, and in a race they need to get their horse into a good position to sprint to the end)

"To take on Gov. Ron DeSantis and U.S. Sen. Marco Rubio" means to run against them in an election. The next election is in 2022.

So in total it means

> As (or while)  many different people (from the Democratic Party) begin trying to get in a good position to win the primary races to become the Democrat opponents of DeSantis and Rubio...