# Which definition? "Run up debts of XXXXX"

Tags: definition

This is the continuation of the [**last question.**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/277122/jockeying-begins-to-take-on-gov-ron-desantis-and-u-s-sen-marco-rubio-in-2022)

There is a line saying,

> Meanwhile, Florida’s Democratic Party **ran up debts of up to $860,000** and had to cancel health insurance coverage for party employees late last year — prompting the national party and other states' party organizations to provide some assistance.

According to [**a dictionary,**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/run-up) run up means in transitive sense,

> 1: BID UP ( raise the price of XXXXX ).

> 2: to stitch together quickly

> 3: to erect hastily

> 4: to achieve by accumulating

I think it sounds like the definition is 4. Am I correct? Thank you for resurrecting me again and again(m_m).

Comment: I don't know if this is a British/American difference, but to me meaning 4 can _only_ be used in a negative sense: you can run up a debt or a deficit but not a lead. The example in Merriam Webster seems strange to me. In the iWeb corpus, "run up a bill/tab/debt/deficit" totals 177 instances, while "run up a score/balance/credit" totals 41. "Run up a lead" has only one instance.

Comment: @ColinFine Thanks for the info.(m_m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run up a debt, deficit, bill, loss, etc, is, indeed, to accumulate these things.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative wording would be to say that they incurred the debts.